# Can not install Mercurial (Depends)

Tags: mercurial

I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial mercurial-common
```

Result:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mercurial : Depends: mercurial-common (= 4.0.2~trusty1) but 4.1~rc~trusty1 is to be installed
 mercurial-common : Recommends: mercurial (= 4.1~rc~trusty1) but 4.0.2~trusty1 is to be installed
                    Breaks: mercurial (< 4.1~rc~trusty1) but 4.0.2~trusty1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Removes mercurial-common, installed Mercurial again - it did not help.

Comment: It seems that `mercurial-common` tries to install a release candidate (rc). Did you add a ppa to your sources list (e.g. `ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases`)? Did you do `sudo apt-get update` before install?

Comment: @ridgy +1 for the point about PPAs and update. @baron You might also try doing `sudo apt install mercurial=4.1~rc~trusty1`

Comment: @ridgy yes, i use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases` and `sudo apt-get update`. The result is the same.

Comment: @Nonny-Moose `E: Version '4.1~rc~trusty1' for 'mercurial' was not found`. Indeed, something with PPA..

Comment: Look at https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases/+packages - there are build failures reported in release  mercurial - 4.1~rc~trusty1.

Comment: @baron Yeah, then the PPA doesn't have the version it's supposed to have. Remove it and compile from source or just use the main repos.

Comment: Guys, thank you. Not noticed that version failed. Returned is the previous